# Sum the results of vlookups across multiple columns

Tags: arrays, excel, range, vlookup

I'm trying to avoid repetition. The following formula works:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C3,'Business Goals'!$A$3:$C$8,3),0)+
IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D3,'Business Goals'!$A$3:$C$8,3),0)+
IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E3,'Business Goals'!$A$3:$C$8,3),0)+
IFERROR(VLOOKUP($F3,'Business Goals'!$A$3:$C$8,3),0)+
IFERROR(VLOOKUP($G3,'Business Goals'!$A$3:$C$8,3),0)+
IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H3,'Business Goals'!$A$3:$C$8,3),0)
```

Essentially I want to sum up columns C:H, and the values I want to sum are all stored within the same lookup table.

For my own sanity, if you're providing an answer and it doesn't REQUIRE INDEX/MATCH please express your answer using VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array formulas to achieve this (see caveat below):

```
=SUM(('Business Goals'!$A$3:$A$8=$C3:$H3)*'Business Goals'!$C$3:$C$8)
```

This uses the fact that in arithmetic operations, `(x=y)` evaluates to 1 if true or 0 otherwise.  `('Business Goals'!$A$3:$A$8=$C3:$H3)` creates a rectangular array which is like a lookup table with a 1 where the values in `$C3:$H3` match those in `'Business Goals'!$A$3:$A$8`.  That is then multiplied by the corresponding values in `'Business Goals'!$C$3:$C$8` and finally the whole lot is summed over.

**Remember** to paste the formula into the formula bar and then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` otherwise it won't be recognised as an array formula.

This works **provided** you wanted the "exact match" form of `VLOOKUP` (e.g. `VLOOKUP(A1,B2:G30,FALSE)`) which returns an error if it can't find the data, rather than the default approximate match which you have.  That assumes a sorted list and returns the next largest row if it can't find an exact match.  I don't think there is a neat way of doing it if you need the approximate match.

Comment: thanks - copied from row 2 in my test sheet!  I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Outstanding! I've seen formulae like this before an couldn't understand why there was multiplication involved. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @TomAuger the ",0" was a mistake - now removed!  {=A*B} will return an array, but in this case we want the sum of all the elements in the array hence `SUM`.

Comment: @TomAuger I found the Formulas/Evaluate Formula button in Excel handy for understanding how array formulas work - it will show you the intermediate arrays (between curly brackets and with comma as the column delimiter and semicolon as the row delimiter).